# How to call function of one activity from another activity

Tags: android

Actually i want to call a function of one activity from another activity..i write a simple code  for that but its not working..and show runtime error..please check the code...if there any mistake..

code for activity1:

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity2  
{
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main2);

                call();
        }
        public void call()
        {
                showToast("Helloo");
        }
}
```

code for activity2:

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity 
{

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);
        }
        public void showToast(String s)
        {
                EditText t=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                t.setText(s);
        }
}
```

Comment: Please post the logcat of the exception

Comment: public void showToast(String s)
        {
                EditText t=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                t.setText(s);        }   Edit code for the above method. change its signature . pass activity reference to it. and then call findviewById on that activity and not current activity in which method is declared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're calling `findViewById` on a view that doesn't exist.

`Activity1` is extending `Activity2`.

You call the `super.onCreate` in `Activity1` which calls the `onCreate` in `Activity2` which calls `setContentView()` for `R.layout.main`.

I'm guessing your text `R.id.editText1` is in the main layout.

When `Activity1` returns from the call to `super.onCreate` it immediately resets the content layout to `main2`.

The edit text box that you are trying to edit no longer exists.  `findViewById` can not find it because the layout is not active.  Thus it crashes.

To fix it try this:

```
public class Activity1 extends Activity2  
{
        private EditText et;
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main2);

                et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                call();
        }
        public void call()
        {
                showToast("Helloo", et);
        }
}
```

Where `R.id.editText2` is an edit text box in the layout `main2`.

In Activity2:

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity 
{

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);
        }
        public void showToast(String s, EditText t)
        {
                t.setText(s);
        }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you use R.layout.main in Activity1 instead of R.layout.main2.  You won't have to make any other changes than that.  It should work as well, but you're introducing a lot of confusion in the code I think.

Answer (score 2):

First, this is a bad design principle since only one Activity is active at a time. You can make a method static and then you can cross call them but at that point it should be in some sort of common util class.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to declare your `showToast()` method as `public static`, this way you can call it without having an instance of `Activity2`.

Answer (score 1):

if you put it in as static you should declare it on your main activity